# Check the border of a sprite in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I'm trying to use Window.ClientBounds.Width to check if the sprite is within the windows border. I want to use this in the another class than the Game1.cs. Let's say I have a Car.cs class and inside that class I want to have an own Update method that check if it's inside the borders of the window, but I cant use Window.ClientBounds.Width this!? I have also tested to create a static int gameBorder = Window.ClientBounds.Width; inside Game1.cs and reach the value that way, but this doesn't work either?! Help is preciated! Thanks!

Is there a better way than stackowerflow for XNA questions that is free?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When constructing the Car class I would pass a reference to the Game that the car is supposed to be part of or the GraphicsDevice that it's supposed to be displayed on.

```
class Car
{
   // Keep a reference to the game inside the car class.
   Game game;

   public Car (Game game)
   { 
      this.game = game;
   }

   public void Update(.....
   { 
       // You can access the client bounds here.
       // the best thing about this method is that
       // if the bounds ever changes, you don't have
       // to notify the car, it always has the correct
       // values.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to go to all that work, and waste all that memory.

XNA has a very exact and specific means of testing positions of objects.

You can simply pass in the GraphicsDeviceManager graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth and Height methods to get the width and height of your window.

From there, you know whether an object is visible in the game window based on whether it is within the rectangle of those positions.

So lets say you set your back buffer width and height to be 640x480.

Then you would simply check to see if the bounds of your texture are within that rectangle.

So, here's your function:

```
public void CheckIfWithinWindow(int width, int height)
{
    Rectangle wndRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    Rectangle carRect = new Rectangle(carPos.X, carPos.Y, carTexture.Width, carTexture.Height);

    if (wndRect.Intersects(carRect))
    {
         //carTexture is within currently visible window bounds!
    }
    else
    {
         //carTexture is NOT within currently visible window bounds!
    }
}
```

Then you can call this function from your Update Method in your starting XNA class like so.

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
     myCar.CheckIfWithinWindow(graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth, graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight);
}
```

Hope that helps. Have fun.

Comment: So pass in 2 value types every update() method instead of passing 1 reference type in the construction? not sure which wastes more memory. Also with the game class you have access to game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Bounds.Intersects(..) which doesn't require you to create another rectangle.

Comment: The format you've used passes in and copies the whole game object and keeps an instance of it in memory the whole time. This is alot more expensive than quickly passing and copying two ints.

As for my rectangles, via your method, to check if you're within bounds, they'd still need to use rectangle objects, or call a member function from the Game object that will do the same thing, to detect if the object is within the window bounds.

Comment: To put it simply, it's not that passing one object is cheaper than passing two, it's that the GameObject you're passing in is a larger memory object than two ints. A game object that has tons of variables within it (on top of the initial memory for the basic GameObject itself) is going to be larger than the 8 bytes that are those two ints.

Comment: But you could, perchance use a "ref" in there and then we'd be all hunky dory, that'd be relatively the same efficiency as what I've done.

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong but the game class is passed by reference meaning its just a pointer to the memory location that the object currently resides at, if you alter a property on the class is persists through all references. I'm only guessing here but I seriously doubt the viewport recalculates it's bounds every time you access the property.

Comment: I'm not saying the viewport recalculates it's bounds. I'm saying the comparison to see if the object is within the bounds does. Also, your implementation didn't use a reference. It was copying the Game Object.

Comment: I however do agree that passing by reference is more elegant. However, from past experience, I've found this way to work better for code clarity.

Comment: I don't mean to be a douche about this but the ref keyword is not required to pass the game by reference since it's a reference type. I wouldn't normally keep on about this but it's a pretty fundamental part of .net programming. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Wow, didn't know that (I'm a C++ guy at heart, and sadly live in the world of "if it's not passed by reference, it isn't"). My graphics work is largely done via DX9 and C++. I didn't even know C# did this. Damn that's cool. Thanks mate!